# Is $1$ raised to any complex power equal to $1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I just saw a solution that says it is since,  for any complex number $z$

$$1^z = e^{z\log1} = e^{z(0)} = 1$$

However, isn't this only true for the principle branch of $1^z$, since by definiton, (letting capital L denote the princple value of log

$$\log1 = \operatorname{Log}1 +  i2\pi k$$

for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @martini, I think the definition of complex powers is $z^\alpha = e^{\alpha \log z}$.  You just did $z^\alpha = e^{\log z}$

Comment: The real number $1$ raised to any complex power is equal to $1$. The complex number $1$ raised to any complex power may not be.

Comment: @Dan You're right, of course.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct: $1$ is not the only value of $1^z$ if $z$ is not an integer.  For example, $-1$ is also one of the values of $1^{1/2}$.  In general the possible values of $1^z$ are $e^{2 \pi i n z}$ for integers $n$.

Answer (score -3):

$1.~~$ Euler's identity: $$e^{i~\pi}+1=0 \implies e^{i~\pi} = -1 \implies (e^{i~\pi})^i = (-1)^i = e^
{-\pi}\tag1$$

$2.~~$ $$e^{i~\pi}+1=0 \implies 1^i = (- e^{i~\pi})^i \implies 1^i = (-1)^i~(e^{i~\pi})^i) = 
 = e^{-\pi}~e^{-\pi} \implies 1^i = e^{-2~\pi}$$

Hence $~1~$ raised to the power of $~i~$ equals $~-0.0018674427\cdots~$

Strange fact or wrong?

Comment: How do you justify $(e^{i\pi})^i=(e^{i\cdot i\pi})$? The rule $(b^z)^w=b^{zw}$ does not hold generally when $z,w$ can be complex. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_a_positive_real_base).